# JS Проблема с циклом

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код:

```
function turnBot(){
  var min = 15;

  for(var i = 0; i < cardN[0].length; i++){
    var data = explode(".", cardN[0][i]);
    var number = data[0];
    var mast = data[1];

    console.log('number' + number + 'min:' + min);

    if(number < min){
      min = number;
      console.log('MIN:' + min);
      var cardName = number + mast;
    }
  }

  clearCard(cardName);
  addCardForTable(cardName);
  enabledTurnPlayer();
}
```

Пытаюсь в функции выполнить условие  `if(number < min)`, но оно не выполняется:

[image: console log]

Скрин кода:

[image: function]

Вопрос: почему не выполняется условие?

Comment: Все правильно, '9' < '10'.

Comment: да но условие не срабатывает, спасибо КЕП я и так знаю что '9' < '10'

Comment: Ни вы, ни @PavelMayorov оба не правы, поскольку "9" больше "10" т. к. сравнение идет по строкам, а не как числа. Приводите все к числам явно через `parseInt` и не будет проблем.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте код в тело вопроса в виде текста, а не изображения. Для этого используйте ссылку «[edit]», расположенную под метками вопроса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возможно, у вас есть проблема с типами. Ошибка заключается в том, что вы сравниваете строки, что есть ошибка, ибо:

```
"8"<"10"
false
8<10
true
```

Попробуйте явно преобразовать значения в int:

```
...
if (parseInt(num) < parseInt(min)) {
...
```

PS. Также рекомендую вам пользоваться дебагером и брякпоинтами (есть в современных браузерах из коробки), либо делать вывод более красивым. Пример красивого вывода:

```
console.log("Number:", number, "; Min:", min)
```

С таким выводом вы можете явно проследить тип переменной, а не терять его во время преобразований.

Comment: Спасибо, забыл об parseInt